# How to pass label to matrix of XGBoost JVM Package

Tags: xgboost

I found the JVM package quick start example of creating data matrix at [official doc](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/jvm/java_intro.html)

```java
float[] data = new float[] {1f,2f,3f,4f,5f,6f};
int nrow = 3;
int ncol = 2;
float missing = 0.0f;
DMatrix dmat = new DMatrix(data, nrow, ncol, missing);

// and a DMatrix could be called by train method
Booster booster = XGBoost.train(dmat, params, nround, watches, null, null);
```

However, the doc says the JVM package DMatrix usage is the same with Python package, in Python, there is a label parameter

```py
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data, label=label)
```

But I could not find any in JVM package, how to set the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XGBoost JVM package we could use `dMatrix.setLabel(labelArray)` to set the label (According to XGBoost github issue page)